# applying a function to a timeseries in a R dataframe

Tags: r, apply

I'm trying to apply a function to a column in a dataframe that contains dates and keep getting an error. I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong.

My dataframe:

```
                 dates total
 1 2014-12-08 01:10:00 163.7
 2 2014-12-08 01:10:00 163.9
 3 2014-12-08 01:12:00 163.6
 4 2014-12-08 08:27:00 163.0
 5 2014-12-08 08:35:00 163.7
 6 2014-12-08 08:39:00 162.4
```

I want to replace the dates by either 'morning' or 'night' or alternatively created a new column with 'morning' or 'night'.  the approach that i took involved unclassing the date so i could get the hour.  I defined a night as before 4am or after 5pm.  I put this in a function called timeofday:

```
timeofday <- function(x) {
  bmk <- unclass(x)
  if (bmk$hour < 4) {
    return("night")
  } else if (bmk$hour > 17) {
    return("night")
  } else {
    return("morning")
 }
}
```

I then did the following:

```
timeofday(df$dates)

Warning message:
In if (bmk$hour < 4) { :
   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Any help on identifying the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could also use `cut` as in:

```
cut(unclass(x)$hour-7,c(0,15,24)-8,c('night','morning'))
```

(note that you have to shift your frame of reference so that you don't have two 'night' categories with this solution)

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains this if statement

```
 if (bmk$hour < 4)
```

If bmk is a vector, like in your case, you have an if statement containing a vector and therefore it will take account of the first element of the vector only.

This is the workaround

```
sapply(df$dates, timeofday)
```

Comment: still didn't work for me.  Error in bmk$hour : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors